# html5 listbox not a dropdown

Tags: html, listbox

Is anyone aware of a way (without using a third party control) to create a listbox, meaning the list is always visible? In other words, I don’t want a drop-down list that requires a click to see the list. I want the equivalent of the original winforms listbox as we have in desktop windows apps.

To reiterate, I am aware there are third party controls like Telerik, etc. I want to avoid adding dependencies on third party controls.

This lack of a true listbox control in HTML5 has been a pet peeve of mine for awhile now. I’m hoping someone has come up with a viable solution.

Cheers,
-=Cameron

Thus isn’t about a bug or programming issue so there is nothing to list under “What did you try “.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't a `select` with `multiple` attribute what you are looking for ?

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple#select

Comment: Holy crap. Yes! Thanks very much.

-=Cameron